# How to set a value to a combobox from a table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagrid

i have a datagrid with the fifth column being a combobox.

*this is the code:*

```
            //...
            string rq = "select * from RESview";
            SqlDataReader r = DB.selection(rq);
            while (r.Read())
            { 
                DATAGRID.Rows.Add(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6]);
            }
            r.Close();
```

r[4] is the value of what i want the combobox to show,
the combobox have 4 other option which are the one that can be found in the Database.
so i'm asking is it possible to set a value to each combobox when adding a row or selecting a combobox value from the already created collection depending on what r[4] is.

Comment: If r[4] is a string then yes it is possible.

Comment: oh thanks a lot ! i realized that i had some values in the db table that were not in the collection and it kept giving me a system argument exception

Comment: That will be a problem if the string data does not match one of the items in the combo box. If you don't know all the different items, it may be better to get the items for the comb box FROM all the different strings in your data base. That way you will know they will match.

Comment: Yes, you can set that comboBox item as selected if that is not in the list or add new value if required.